# How do I increase command line argument size or limit in windows command prompt

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi I have created a JAVA program which uses ProcessBuilder to start command prompt, java passes command with some arguments to the console and then command prompt is responsible to handle the command, everything is working fine until the command line argument is too long. Actually I am using phantomjs as a command and passing multiple urls as a arguments to the command prompt. 
Eg: Java generated string-

`phantomjs download.js --url=http://google.com, http://yahoo.com, http://website.com..................http://demo.com`

When I was passing 100's of urls then it works fine but when increases to 1000's of urls then its not working. I know, it happens because of argument buffer size. When I was trying to pass 1000's urls then it exceeds the maximum byte limit of the command line for windows. So there is any other way to pass this value into file or can we increase the limit of command line arguments.

Please give me some solution for this.

Comment: drop all of them in a file and read it off it? cant the download.js read off a file?

Comment: Have you tried dividing it over multiple calls? You said yourself that doing it for 100s of calls works fine, so what if you do it for 200 requests at a time and concatenate the results?

Comment: Yes @govi keeping into a file is a solution for this but I will keep this option for last, because generating will create some space and my script will also take some time(seconds or ms) to create/read file.

Comment: Actuallu @Voidpaw I have 6000+ data so I already divided into 6 slots.

Comment: the closest thing i can think of is using 'getconf ARG_MAX' and use that to segment your calls.. then again, that has nothing to do with "increasing the limit".. if you want to however, systems which allow to change it at run time (AIX), by reconfiguration (UnixWare, IRIX), by recompiling (e.g. Linux) or by applying patches (HP-UX 10).. if these are viable.. more info http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just passing a filename as argument ?
The target file contains the list of urls (JSON.stringify or simply one per line)

For example

```
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length === 1) {
  console.log('download.js <filename>');
  phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var filename = args[1];
    var stream = fs.open(filename, 'r') 

    var line;
    while(line=stream.readLine()) {
        //do want you want here
        console.log(line);
    }

    phantom.exit(0);
}
```

Run with

```
>phantomjs download.js mytestfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Cybermaxs for suggestion with example. I think this is only solution for my problem is reading from a file. There is no way to increase the size of command line argument in windows, so I have to  use this. Thanks for all to give your attention.